# Drop measurement that belong to a specific retention policy

Tags: influxdb

Recently, we migrated our data from measurement 'users' with retention policy autogen (default) to retention policy sixty_days (sixty_days.users).
So we don't need anymore the data in autogen.users.

How can we remove it without harming the data in sixty_days.users?

This is a strange behavior because when we insert data to sixty_days.users - it's not applied on autogen.users, but when we try to delete / drop - it removes it from both of them.

We tried to use DROP, and DELETE by time, but without success.

We expect to remove only data in a measurement that belongs to a specific RT.

Answer (score 3):

As Nikolay Manolov mentioned in his answer, you cannot specify retention policy as part of DELETE OR DROP command. But do we really need it?

After tested I confirmed, your issue is related to  using same measurement name along with different retention policies. So a better hack may be using a temporary measurement name other than 'user' until you delete the old copy with default retention policy.

```
select * into "sixty_days".temp_user from "autogen".user group by *;
delete from user;
select * into "sixty_days".user from "sixty_days".temp_user group by *;
delete temp_user;
```

You need to group by clause as part of above queries to avoid tags converted to fields by default.

Comment: An almost classic swap question in interviews :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This was not supported and it seems it still is not.

It is the intended behavior that DELETE affects all retention policies. And, yes, it is inconsistent for example with a SELECT where you can select from a particular retention policy only. See the docs on this https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/database_management/#retention-policy-management

I suppose a not very elegant workaround could be to apply a retention_policy_tag to the data which would then allow you to delete data from particular retention policies.

EDIT: in your case, since the data is already there, you can't apply a tag. You could do a migration via copying the data into a temporary measurement, cleaning up, and then copying the data back. Alternatively, wait 60 days and then delete everything that is older, until which time your data will be duplicated.

Comment: I think I'll stick to your advice with the removal of last 60 days. Thanks!